# design issues in IE 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, html-lists

**Hi** ,This is my **HTML**

```
<div style="width:220px;float:left;" id="radio_text">
    <ul style="width:20px;float:left;display:block;">
        <li style="list-style:none;line-height:13px;height:13px;float:left;"><input type="radio" name="radio_flag" checked="true" /></li>
        <li style="list-style:none;line-height:13px;height:13px;float:left;"><input type="radio" name="radio_flag" /></li>
        <li style="list-style:none;line-height:13px;height:13px;float:left;"><input type="radio" name="radio_flag" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="width:200px;float:left;">
        <li style="list-style:none;line-height:13px;height:13px;width: 200px;float:left;">Show All</li>
        <li style="list-style:none;line-height:13px;height:13px;width: 200px;float:left;">Show Only Members</li>
        <li style="list-style:none;line-height:13px;height:13px;width: 200px;float:left;">Show Only Accepted Contacts</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My **CSS**

```
#radio_text ul{float:left;}
#radio_text ul li{background: none;border:none;color: #000000;float: left;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 11px;font-weight: normal;margin-right: 2px;padding: 1px 7px;text-align: left;}
```

and My **Outputs**

[image]

Please Help me to show it properly in **IE 7**

**Thanks**

Comment: You should move your inline styles to the external stylesheet. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/rdkjk/ looks fine in IE7 here.

Comment: Why are you separating the radio buttons from their labels?

Comment: Well , the code you posted seems to look fine in IE7 , 
unless you missed to paste some of the css.
Also agree with @Kyle and @jswolf19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact situation you are programming, byt why wouldn't you change your **HTML** to this :

```
<div style="width:220px;float:left;" id="radio_text">
    <ul style="float:left;display:block;">
        <li style="list-style:none;line-height:13px;height:13px;">
            <input type="radio" name="radio_flag" checked="true" />
            <span class="radio-text">Show All</span>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style:none;line-height:13px;height:13px;">
            <input type="radio" name="radio_flag" />
            <span class="radio-text">Show Only Members</span>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style:none;line-height:13px;height:13px;">
            <input type="radio" name="radio_flag" />
            <span class="radio-text">Show Only Accepted Contacts</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This way, the text is automatically next to the radio button. You could also wrap a **<label>** tag around the radio button and the span, so the radio button gets checked when a user clicks on the text.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="rbtn"/><span>text</span></label>
```

And I agree, it is best to place all the style attributes in the external stylesheet.